# Access to elements of JSON array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

My data on server is in the form of JSON array of objects. If I want to print the first object, how can I access its first object? Format of data is:

```
[
  {
   "eventId": "8577",
   "datasetId": "34",
   "nodeId": "8076",
   "typeId": "4",
   "type": "TempAndHum",
  "status": "Temp : 35, Hum : 83",
  "datasetName": "test active set",
  "mode": "shared",
  "xmlFragment": "Absent",
  "gpsLat": "-23.549999",
  "gpsLong": "-46.633301",
  "contributor": "SanatIITD",
  "addedOn": "2015-04-21 08:03:16",
  "updatedOn": "2015-04-21 08:03:16"
  },
 {
  "eventId": "8576",
  "datasetId": "34",
  "nodeId": "8076",
  "typeId": "4",
  "type": "TempAndHum",
  "status": "Temp : 34, Hum : 81",
  "datasetName": "test active set",
  "mode": "shared",
   "xmlFragment": "Absent",
  "gpsLat": "-23.549999",
  "gpsLong": "-46.633301",
  "contributor": "SanatIITD",
  "addedOn": "2015-04-21 08:03:11",
 "updatedOn": "2015-04-21 08:03:11"
 },
 {
    "eventId": "8575",
   "datasetId": "34",
   "nodeId": "8076",
   "typeId": "4",
   "type": "TempAndHum",
   "status": "Temp : 33, Hum : 80",
   "datasetName": "test active set",
   "mode": "shared",
  "xmlFragment": "Absent",
  "gpsLat": "-23.549999",
   "gpsLong": "-46.633301",
   "contributor": "SanatIITD",
  "addedOn": "2015-04-21 08:03:05",
  "updatedOn": "2015-04-21 08:03:05"
 },
]
```

I tried with data[0], but end up with printing "[". I tried with JSON.stringify also and then split with "," but that gives me first element of the object, not the whole first object. I need to print the whole first object which is within the curly braces. Is there any way so that I can access like array and by doing document.getElementById("Id")=myData[0], so that I don't need to print all elements within the curly braces separately. Please suggest me some solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @vishwa I am doing it in javascript

Comment: If you have JSON, you have to parse it first.

Answer (score 0):

use `var dataArray = JSON.parse(dataString)` first,
your data is a string at the moment.

Then use `dataArray[0]`

Comment: Isn't it array of object?

Comment: yes it is but it is stringified, you need to parse it first.

Comment: @ArchanaRoy Apparently not: "*I tried with data[0], but end up with printing "[".*" That sounds like a string to me.

Comment: $("#submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
     
        type: 'GET',
   
        url: "resource.php",
   
        success:function(data){
    alert(data);
      var  myData = JSON.parse(data);  
                  
                 
              document.getElementById("aami").innerHTML= myData[0];   }
  
          });
   Not getting where I am wrong? When I run this code I am getting         [ object object].

Comment: Assign some value form the object not whole object to the html element. Like `document.getElementById("aami").innerHTML= myData[0].datasetName`.

Comment: Thanks @atinder , I am able to do that, but what my mentor wants me to print data within the curly braces with the help of single variable, like if I consider all elements inside the curly braces as a single element, and then can I access it by any method.

Comment: `document.getElementById("aami").innerHTML= JSON.stringify(myData[0]);`

Comment: Here in status I am getting two different data like temp and Hum. If i want to display them seperately how can I do it?